# Why do mobile hotspots when connected to laptop showing a default gateway even though the data is switched off?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, ip, lan

I have switched off my mobile data and switched on portable mobile hotspot and connected it to my computer and here is the ip configurations as shown in the image
[image]

My question is how this network is formed and how the default gateway is present eventhough we are not connected to internet and what exaclty does this justifies?

Another question is when i switched on the data inside my mobile and hotspot is restarted the same ip configurations were present without even slight variations how is this possible?

Please help as i have been struggling with this since a while.

Comment: what do you mean connected to computer? Phone connected via cable or do you mean connect the computer TO the hotspot wia wireless? Which device outputs that ip configuration - the computer or the phone?

Comment: Connected through hotspot via wireless

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to your questions:**

1. **Why always set Default Gateway?** This is done for simplicity - why complicate things by checking if mobile data are activated? The purpose of mobile hotspot is to connect computers to internet via mobile data adapter ON THE HOTSPOT. You might as well set the gateway to the IP address of the hotspot each time. It just doesn't make sense to set it to anything else. If you want such network design - don't bother with hotspot program for phones.
2. **Why am i receiving same IP address each time?** This is probably because your hotspot program remembers your computer. Each network device has unique identifier named MAC Address - your hotspot saves MAC Address of your Computer wireless adapter and when you connect again, it will give him same IP.

**Simplified explanation of how networking works:**

Mobile hotspot on your phone behaves a lot like regular wireless router. This is what happens, when you connect your computer to the hotspot:

1. First, connection between the devices is established via 802.11 protocol. This is also when your computer is authenticated - for example when you protect your hotspot with password.
2. By successfully connecting to the hotspot your computer joins its network.
3. Now the computer needs to know structure of the network so regular programs can communicate with other computers or the hotspot. This when `IP address`, `Subnet Mask` and `Default Gateway` come to play. The `Mask` tells computer which IP addresses are on the same network. If you need to send data to IP address which is on the same network, it will go there directly. However, if you try to contact IP address that isn't on your network, all data will be send to `Default Gateway` with instruction where to go next.
4. Because it is inconvenient to set all of this manually, most routers and hotspots are running an extra program named `DHCP Server`. This allows your computer to automatically set IP address, Subnet Mask and Default Gateway to numbers that your hotspot tells it to. It can configure additional things like DNS. Finally, DHCP server can remember your computer's wireless card unique name (`MAC Address`) and assign the same IP address to you each time you connect.